# Which is the proper way to create Entity classes in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine-orm, doctrine

According to doctrine documentation am reading, it says concerning using

> Entity classes

that all of the fields should be protected or private (not public) and this is the quote.

> When creating entity classes, all of the fields should be protected or
>   private (not public ), with getter and setter methods for each one
>   (except $id ). The use of mutators allows Doctrine to hook into calls
>   which manipulate the entities in ways that it could not if you just
>   directly set the values with entity#field = foo;

While the 6th edition of an advanced PHP book(One of the best selling books on PHP and other programming books out there are being written by this company) I just read says this

> In most cases, private properties are strongly preferred over public
>   ones. However, in the case of entity classes, you should use public
>   properties. The sole purpose of an entity class is to make some data
>   available. It’s no good having a class representing an author if you
>   can’t even read the author’s name!

I understand that the pattern used by doctrine might slightly be different from the book approach but when you see statements like this, you get to wonder which is which. Which of the statement is wrong and which of the statement is right

The entire house should please enlighten me

Comment: I avoid public properties like the plague, because the internal workings of a class have no business spilling out.  It makes things harder to maintain, and add stuff to later.  That said I do have specific Data type objects just for handling data, that use public properties.  But for something as complex and likely to change as a DB Entity, I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Flagged is primarily opinion based. However, to add my opinion: go for `protected` properties on classes, when you don't make a `final` class, in which case go for `private`. Simple reasoning: a class which may be (partially) overwritten / extended by a child-class should have access to the properties / functionality it's overwriting / extending. Judge for yourself if you want to allow a property / function to be overwritten by a child class, if you don't: make it private.